# Is there an R dplyr method for merge with all=TRUE?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two R dataframes I want to merge. In straight R you can do:

```
cost <- data.frame(farm=c('farm A', 'office'), cost=c(10, 100))
trees <- data.frame(farm=c('farm A', 'farm B'), trees=c(20,30))
merge(cost, trees, all=TRUE)
```

which produces:

```
    farm cost trees
1 farm A   10    20
2 office  100    NA
3 farm B   NA    30
```

I am using `dplyr`, and would prefer a solution such as:

```
left_join(cost, trees)
```

which produces something close to what I want:

```
    farm cost trees
1 farm A   10    20
2 office  100    NA
```

In `dplyr` I can see `left_join`, `inner_join`, `semi_join` and `anti-join`, but none of these does what `merge` with `all=TRUE` does.

Also - is there a quick way to set the NAs to 0? My efforts so far using `x$trees[is.na(x$trees)] <- 0;` are laborious (I need a command per column) and don't always seem to work.

thanks

Comment: what about `plyr::join_all`?

Comment: When you merge with NA's are you expecting teh m x n multiplicity of "matched NA"?

Comment: Would this be sufficient? `library(zoo); cost %.% merge(trees, all = TRUE) %.% lapply(na.fill, fill = 0) %.% as.data.frame()`

Comment: `DF[is.na(DF)]<-0` will turn NA to 0 - on `dplyr` I think that's no.

Comment: No, that would be `outer_join()`, which is not yet implemented: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/96

Comment: Thanks all - I'll use `merge` for now and wait for `outer_join`!

Comment: @hadley: I was just struggling with this too. Can you please add *'outer_join not implemented yet, use base::merge() or other function'* to the plyr::*_join manpage?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The most recent version of `dplyr` (0.4.0) now has a full_join option, which is what I believe you want.

```
cost <- data.frame(farm=c('farm A', 'office'), cost=c(10, 100))
trees <- data.frame(farm=c('farm A', 'farm B'), trees=c(20,30))
merge(cost, trees, all=TRUE)
```

Returns

```
> merge(cost, trees, all=TRUE)
        farm cost trees
    1 farm A   10    20
    2 office  100    NA
    3 farm B   NA    30
```

And

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(cost, trees)
```

Returns

```
> full_join(cost, trees)
Joining by: "farm"
    farm cost trees
1 farm A   10    20
2 office  100    NA
3 farm B   NA    30
Warning message:
joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)
> dat <- join(cost, trees, type = "full")
Joining by: farm
> dat
    farm cost trees
1 farm A   10    20
2 office  100    NA
3 farm B   NA    30

> dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0
> dat
    farm cost trees
1 farm A   10    20
2 office  100     0
3 farm B    0    30
```

Comment: Please do not replace NAs with zeros.